# How to apply noise sample to each member of a vector in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, lapply

I want to add noise to a vector in R. I can do this with a loop:

```
N <- 4; v <- c(1,5,3,8)
for (i in (1:N)) {
   vec[i] <- vec[i] + floor(runif(1, min = -4, max = 4)
}
```

There must be an easy way to use lapply to do this, but it eludes me. Help appreciated.

Comment: Since you use `floor(runif(1, min = -4, max = 4)` it seems you want to create integers. The easier/more direct way of creating random, uniformly distributed integers is to use `?sample`, i.e. in your case: `v + sample(-4:4, length(v), replace = TRUE)`.

Comment: Thanks for that tip. Will make the replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `v` is the `vec`

```
set.seed(24)
v+floor(runif(N, min=-4, max=4))
#[1] -1  2  4  8
```

which is the same as

```
set.seed(24)
for(i in 1:N){
 v[i] <- v[i]+ floor(runif(1, min = -4, max = 4))
 }
v
#[1] -1  2  4  8
```

If you need `apply` family solution

```
set.seed(24)
mapply(`+`, v, floor(runif(N, min=-4, max=4)))
#[1] -1  2  4  8
```

Comment: Thanks! Thought I had tried the first answer and found only one noise sample for all vector elements, but obviously it works! Getting late. Thanks.